# WSO2 EI For loop through Json array

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a below request (i am using WSO2 Enterprise integrator 6.5.0):

And I wanna get this  in jsonpayload which is returned client

```
<ERROR_RESP>
    <ERROR>
        <ECODE>ST-VALS-002</ECODE>
        <EDESC>Record Not Found  for Branch Code-CHO:Currency 1-USD:Currency 2-MN</EDESC>
    </ERROR>
    <ERROR>
        <ECODE>ST-SAVE-024</ECODE>
        <EDESC>Failed to Query Data</EDESC>
    </ERROR>
</ERROR_RESP>
```

It is my tried code to achieve it :

```
<foreach expression="json-eval($.ERROR_RESP.ERROR)">
    <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
            { 
                "ErrorCode" : "$1", 
                "ErrorMessage" : "$2"  
            }
                </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.ECODE"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.EDESC"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="ENDLOOP"/>
        </log>
        <loopback/>
    </sequence>
</foreach> 
enter code here
```

I did some search but nothings worked, I think ***foreach expression*** is not right.

Thanks

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

In your sample the Loopback mediator is used. It will be used to move the message to the out flow (response path). Therefore, the Foreach mediator splits the message and sends the first message to the response path and end the flow.

You can prepare the XML payload and convert it to JSON using the messageType property with axis2 scope as follows.

```
    <foreach expression="//ERROR">
        <sequence>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <ERROR xmlns="">
                    <ErrorCode>$1</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorMessage>$2</ErrorMessage>
                 </ERROR>
              </format>
              <args>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//ECODE/text()"/>
                 <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//EDESC/text()"/>
              </args>
           </payloadFactory>
        </sequence>
     </foreach>
     <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```

The final message will be like this:

```
{
    "ERROR_RESP": {
        "ERROR": [
            {
                "ErrorCode": "ST-VALS-002",
                "ErrorMessage": "Record Not Found  for Branch Code-CHO:Currency 1-USD:Currency 2-MN"
            },
            {
                "ErrorCode": "ST-SAVE-024",
                "ErrorMessage": "Failed to Query Data"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: <property expression="$body/RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_RES/FCUBS_BODY/FCUBS_ERROR_RESP/ERROR_RESP/ERROR"
name="myPath1"/> this is my full path to get this XMLNode (SOAP message btw)
I am logging this prop but nothing shows

 <foreach expression="//ERROR"> is it right ?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, foreach mediator in EI 6.5.0 does not support "json-eval()" expressions. This [feature](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4121) will be included in the upcoming versions.

As a workaround, you can use XPath inside the expression. You can use this blog as an example. https://medium.com/@Manuri/wso2-esb-foreach-mediator-example-87f041e2a912

Comment: Thank you for reply Arunan, 
According to my response what is my Xpath? 
Is it like -> //ERROR_RESP/ERROR?ECODE ?

Comment: //ERROR_RESP/ERROR would suffice. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Sample+18%3A+Transforming+a+Message+Using+ForEach+Mediator

Comment: This feature is available from EI 6.6.0 onwards